# The input fields do not have the same width. How to resolve this CSS challenge?

Tags: html, css

Q. How can I get the name input field the same size as the other input fields? As you can see the width is not exactly the same. I tried everything, am clueless at this stage.

On Firefox and Opera it seems to look good. 
It doesn't however look good on Chrome and Chrome Canary. I am using the latest version of Chrome.

When I take out `padding-right: 0px;` it looks good. But I haven't written this code anywhere in my css and I can not change this or take this out. If I write `padding-right: 0;` on `input#name{}` nothing happens.

See website: http://demo.chilipress.com/epic3/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/9gvXK/

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="contact">
        <form>
            <fieldset class="name">
                <label for="name" class="name group">Name</label>
                <input id="name" name="name" required pattern="[A-Za-z-0-9]+\s[A-Za-z]+" title="firstname lastname" />
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="email">
                <label for="email" class="email group">Email</label>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required title="Submit a valid 
                Email">
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="phone">
                <label for="phone" class="phone group">Telephone</label>
                <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" pattern="(\+?\d[- .]*){7,17}" required title="Submit an international, national or local phone number" />
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="message">
                <label class="message group">Message</label>
                <input type="text" id="message" required/>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="send">
                <input type="submit" value="Send" class="sendButton">
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
fieldset {
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
label {
    color: #d8d9de;
    font-family:'apple_chancerychancery';
    font-size: 1.6vw;
    float: left;
}
input {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(255, 240, 260, 0.5);
}
#name, #email, #phone, #message {
    color: #253c93;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px dotted #29FF00;
    font-family:'Calibri', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    width: 75%;
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
}
textarea {
    vertical-align: top;
}
div#inner-editor {
    padding: 30px;
}
#message {
    padding-top: 10%;
}
.sendButton {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    color: #d8d9de;
    font-size: 1.6vw;
    font-family:'apple_chancerychancery';
    padding: 1.5% 5%;
    width: 22%;
    min-width: 61px;
    text-align: center;
    border: none;
    margin: 0 40%;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 9px rgba(199, 255, 100, 0.73), inset -2px -2px 9px rgba(199, 255, 100, 0.73);
}
```

As you can notice the name input field is does not have the same with as the other
  input fields.

[image]

Comment: Please DO NOT link to a live site. Here is why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: Adding CSS and HTML to the question :)

Comment: Fiddle added above: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/9gvXK The problem doesn't occur.

Comment: Just looked on Chrome Version 33.0.1750.154 and it appears fine, no space at the front.

Comment: Also fine in IE11 and Firefox 27.0.1.

Comment: Then what could it be. 

I also cleared the cache and I still have the same problem. 

When a friend of mine looked at the site on his (bigger screen) and resized it, he had no issues. 

I'm dazzled by this since I only have this problem on Chrome and it seems I am the only one who has this problem.

Comment: @isherwood, I clicked on the link of your fiddle and it also shows bad there. 

I made a print screen of it but don't know how to share it here.

Comment: You haven't mentioned your operating system. That can be a factor.

Comment: I'm using MAC OS. 

I'm thinking about deleting Chrome and installing it again. 

When I load the page, the name input field has the same width for half a second and then it jumps 1px to the right (and it becomes shorter in width compared to the other input fields).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run you site in private navigation (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>)

Your extensions might modify your page sometimes... I had an extension that made an error on my javascript console one time.

If it works, try to remove one by one your extensions to see which one interact with the css...

Comment: Absolutely Brilliant. Worked for me!!

Comment: Wow, glad it helps, what was the extension that make this problem?

Comment: It's an extension called LastPass. It can create passwords for any kind of form input. 
Even before the whole thing with NSA got popped up in the news, I was trying to find more secure ways to create passwords for email addresses and passwords for other sign up forms. Usually people tend to have the same password for most their forms. And whenever I created multiple passwords, I started to forget them and had to go through the whole (forgot password button) procedure. 

Thus the lastpass extension.

Comment: I knew it wasn't effecting the website layout for others when they were visiting the site. But I was just very curious to why it wasn't showing properly on my screen whenever I visited. 

So again thanks for the answer :)